# Existence of the absolute value of the limit implies that either $f \ $ or $\bar{f} \ $ is complex-differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise from Remmert.

Let D be  domain in $\mathbb{C} \ $, and $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \ $ a real-differentiable function. Suppose that for some $ c \in D $ the limit

$\lim_{h \to 0} |\frac{f(c + h) - f(c)}{h}|$

exists. Prove that either $f \ $ or $\bar{f} \ $ is complex-differentiable at c.

Any hint ?

Comment: Since $f$ is real-differentiable, one may write that $f(c+h)-f(c)=Ah+B\bar h+o(|h|)$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants. So,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is real-differentiable, one may write that $f(c+h)-f(c)=Ah+B\bar h+o(|h|)$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants (actually, $A=\partial f/\partial z$, $B=\partial f/\partial\bar z$). So, $|\frac{f(c+h)−f(c)}h|=|A+B\frac{|h|}h+\frac{o(|h|)}h|$. If both $A$ and $B$ are non-zero, this limit cannoy exist: denoting $h/|h|$ by $e^{i\theta}$, one sees that $|A+Be^{i\theta}|$ depends on $\theta$, i.e., on the direction along which $h$ tends to zero.

If $B=0$, the function is holomorphic, if $A=0$, the function is antiholomorphic.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why $A=\partial f/\partial z$ and $B=\partial f/\partial\bar z$?