# Complex differentiable function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ differentiable in the real sense. Prove that if $c$ is such that the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{h→0}=\frac{|f(c+h)−f(c)|}{|h|}$$
Then $f$ is differentiable in the complex sense or $\bar{f}$ is differentiable in the complex sense.

$h$ is a complex number.

Comment: $U$ never came into play.

Comment: Is it a hypothesis of more?

Comment: I had thought to use matrix. We know that if f is differentiable in the real sense there exists $Df$, in particular exists $Df(c)$, my biggest question is: under the assumption of the limit, we can ensure that $|Df(c)(w)|$ = $|Df(c)(v)|$ ($v$ and $w$ unit vectors in $U$)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29615/if-a-complex-function-f-is-real-differentiable-then-f-or-overlinef-are?rq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141294/existence-of-the-absolute-value-of-the-limit-implies-that-either-f-or-bar?rq=1